# Bucle lanza excepción cuando debería cargar unas imágenes en un div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Este bucle debería cargar unas imágenes en el div:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var imagen = document.createElement("img");n = document.createElement("img");
    var im = document.createElement("img");
    imagen.src = "C:\\Tarea de tio juego de cartas iguales\\Img\\" + i + ".jpg";
    im.src = "C:\\Tarea de tio juego de cartas iguales\\Img\\" + i + ".jpg";
    document.getElementsByTagName("div").appendChild(imagen);
    document.getElementsByTagName("div").appendChild(im);
}
```

Pero no lo hace y me lanza una excepción en la consola del navegador.
Solo funciona si pongo `document.body.appendChild` pero me gustaría hacerlo con el div, para luego poder modificar sus estilos en CSS.
También he probado usando `getElementsByClassName` y nada.

Comment: Pero nunca asignas nada para la variable `n`

Comment: La razón por la que te lanza una excepción es porque tu computadora NO es un servidor web, puedes usar `file://` antes de la ruta de los archivos para acceder localmente, pero si necesitas algo más dinámico, puedes descargarte un servidor web como XAMPP

Comment: Porque `getElementsByTagName` tiene una S, fijate `getElement S  ByTagName`, es decir, te devuelve una LISTA de elementos y esa lista no tiene la función  `appendChild`, porque `appendChild` es una función de UN nodo

Answer (score 1):

[**`getElementsByTagName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) devuelve una lista o *colección* de elementos, no un único elemento, por lo que no puedes usar directamente el método `appendChild` en toda la colección, sino en uno de sus elementos.

Para que visualices como es el comportamiento de `getElementsByTagName`, supongamos que tenemos varios `div`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
```

```html
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
```

Y así sea un único elemento, de todas formas te devuelve una *colección*:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
```

```html
<div>div 1</div>
```

Por lo que necesitarías acceder a uno de los elementos (que son tus elementos `div`) y no a toda la colección directamente. Por ejemplo, si deseas aplicarle sólo al primer div, tendrías que acceder a la primera posición `0` colocando `getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`, si deseas al segundo `div`, colocas `getElementsByTagName("div")[1]`, sucesivamente:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var imagen = document.createElement("img");
  n = document.createElement("img");
  var im = document.createElement("img");
  imagen.src = "C:\\Tarea de tio juego de cartas iguales\\Img\\" + i + ".jpg";
  im.src = "C:\\Tarea de tio juego de cartas iguales\\Img\\" + i + ".jpg";
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(imagen);
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(im);
}
```

```html
<div>div con imagenes <br></div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
```